# Which SPECIFIC Exception is thrown when maxReceivedMessageSize is exceeded?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, soap, ioexception

I have a WCF web service that is used for uploading a file.
In my web.config file I have set the maxReceivedMessageSize property to a specific value. Now, whenever a client uploads a file that is greater than the specified size, I want to do a specific handling.

What I have seen is that, the exception is thrown while reading the stream (when stream has read bytes greater than the set value, the exception is thrown). And the exception class is IOException.

To identify this specific exception, I have written code like this:

```
catch(System.IO.IOException commEx)
{
     if(commEx.InnerException.HResult.Equals(-2146233087))
     {
         //Handling specific to the maxReceivedMessageSize exception
     }
     else
     {
         //Handling specific to other IO Exceptions
     }
}
```

But the problem is that some other scenario occurred (unknown to me as of now), due to which an IOException has been thrown and the code has gone into the same if() condition.

Hence, I would like to know firstly, if my approach is correct to catch that specific exception. And secondly, if my approach is wrong, what is the correct approach?

**EDIT:** The exception is thrown on the server side (inside my service method which reads the stream) and not on the client side
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a `CommunicationException`, which can be thrown for various causes. If your goal is to show the user of your client application a warning "The file you're trying to upload is too large" while you want the size to be determined serverside and configurable (i.e. not known by the client), you may want to create a service method `GetMaxUploadedFileSize()` which returns this value, so you can warn the user in advance instead of just trying and failing.

Comment: @CodeCaster Firstly, the client of my WCF Service already knows the max size. But still I want to perform a safety check on the server side (some junk data has been added in the network, etc).
Secondly, no I do not just want to show a warning message. I have some specific handling

Comment: If the size exceeds the MaxMessageSize, it will ultimately not end up processing the method you are sending the data in, so no issues and no checks server side should be needed.

Comment: @ChrisBint No. It does process the web method that is exposed. 1) The exception is thrown on the server side (inside the web method). 2) The exception is thrown WHEN reading the bytes from the Stream object in which the file content is stored